# Regex Differences between Java and Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a regex for:

1. Strings of characters beginning and ending with a double quote character, that do not contain control characters, and for which the backslash is used to escape the next character.
2. The paren-star form of comments in Pascal: strings beginning with `(*` and ending with `*)` that do not contain `*)`

I'm trying to write a version in Ruby, then another in Java, but I'm having trouble finding the differences in regex expressions for both. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [This site](http://www.regexplanet.com/) should help you easily test your regular expressions against multiple strings and compare the results. As for the regex format, just read the docs.

Comment: @Tom, that site is super helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a good place to start:

- [specifics for Java](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) (mostly usage of regex in general)
- [specifics for Ruby](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html) (mostly usage of regex in general)
- [flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) (mostly regex syntax and features)

Mostly note that in Ruby your write regexes by delimiting them with `/`, and in Java you need to double-escape everything (`\\` instead of `\`) so that the backslashes get through to the regex engine. Everything else you should find within those links I gave you above.

For the sake of completeness of this answer, I would also like to include Tom's Link to [this online regex tester](http://www.regexplanet.com/), that supports a multitude of regex flavors.

You should go ahead and give both regexes a go. If you encounter any problems, you are more than welcome to ask a new (specific) question, showing your own attempts.

Comment: I will definitely look there, any good sites for learning regex expressions in general?

Comment: @JoeCrawley that site has one of the best regex tutorials, too